# Faster GCD Implementation

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any chance to write a faster GCD than the built-in one in Mathematica?

@Mr.Wizard has written one in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/alternatives-to-while-loops/13129#13129) (although it's not for this purpose) which is 6 times slower on a 100k digits:

```
In[1]:= whileGCD=Module[{a=#,b=#2},While[b!=0,{a,b}={b,Mod[a,b]}];a]&;
In[2]:= Primo[n_]:=Product[i,{i,Prime[Range[n]]}]

In[10]:= prod=Primo[500000];
In[17]:= m=22Primo[20500] +1;

In[16]:= Timing[GCD[m,prod]]
Out[16]= {0.25,1}

In[12]:= Timing[whileGCD[m,prod]]
Out[12]= {1.609,1}
```

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is maybe, if you are a GMP developer with access to some fairly low level NTT (number theory transform) code. Even then it will be difficult.

Comment: I don't have it installed at the moment so I cannot compare them but you may wish to try PARI/GP.  I have found that to be much faster than *Mathematica's* built-in functions in at least one instance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've tried it for Timing[GCD[100000! + 1, 1000000!]] and it is 9 times slower than Mathematica

Comment: I'm actually happy to hear that, though of course that isn't any help to you.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Lichtblau answered this question in the comments

> The short answer is no. The longer answer is maybe, if you are a GMP
>   developer with access to some fairly low level NTT (number theory
>   transform) code. Even then it will be difficult.