# Will built-in functions always perform better than parallelized user-defined functions?

Tags: parallelization, performance-tuning

```
(*Here is an comparison*)
data = {};
For[n = 1, n < 10, n++,
t1 = Timing[ParallelSum[1/i^2, {i, 1, n*100000}]];
t2 = Timing[HarmonicNumber[n*100000, 2]];
AppendTo[data, {t1[[1]], t2[[1]]}]]
data
```

The result is as following which shows the built-in functions always win here.

```
{{0.432000, 0.192000}, {0.896000, 0.500000}, {1.476000, 
0.860000}, {2.228000, 1.236000}, {3.048000, 1.664000}, {3.956000, 
2.128000}, {4.920000, 2.540000}, {5.932000, 2.936000}, {7.140000, 
3.492000}}
```

The question is: If we rewrite a built-in function with parallelized functions, e.g. rewrite

```
HarmonicNumber[n*100000, 2]
```

as

```
ParallelSum[1/i^2, {i, 1, n*100000}]
```

Could we win (in more general case)? If not, then why? And what is the advantage of parallelization? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you read documentation of core language they have clearly specified that if some API exists to provide some functionality, they are so much so optimized that anything you write will be slower than it.Secondly, is it not possible that if required it can switch to parallel processing own its own. Parallel processing is not helpful in all scenarios, hence used only if problem is breakable."Built-in functions will usually run faster than any compiled Mathematica programs you can create."..reference is http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CompilingMathematicaExpressions.html

Comment: Somewhat related: [(1418)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1418/121), [(17360)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17360/121)

Comment: @Blackbird You should consider posting a excerpt from that tutorial as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:I agree but it will be repetition of information.I doubt I can write it better than them.Link shall help.

Comment: @Blackbird "We" try to discourage answering in comments; there's nothing wrong with giving a documentation excerpt as an answer if it the most appropriate one available.  Of course you can embellish it with additional resources if you find them.

Comment: the builtin may well be using a more efficient algorithm than directly crunching the sum...

Comment: @Blackbird Thanks! The built-in functions will win even we test them on super computer (500+ CPU)? If 'yes', then why we need parallelization or gridmathematica? We only need more build-in functions!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! Your answer is very helpful. Maybe some built-in functions already parallelized.

Comment: @Eden You should not assume that the built-in functions do not already make use of parallelism, as a number of them do.  In cases that they do not then yes, assuming sufficiently low overhead and a sufficiently large number of processors your own function may be faster.  Also, not *every* built-in is well optimized; there are cases that even top-level code may be faster, as I believe has been the case with date and time functions at least in past versions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you give some examples to show that our functions can win as an answer to end this question? Maybe you can help me to understand *if some built-in functions already parallelized, why there is no 'lanuching kernels' when we use them?* btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing similar operations.
If you do compare same functions, then `ParallelSum` is clearly faster:

```
data = {};
For[n = 1, n < 5, n++, 
 t1 = AbsoluteTiming[1/ParallelSum[1/i^2, {i, 1, n*100000}]];
 t2 = AbsoluteTiming[1/Sum[1/i^2, {i, 1, n*100000}]];
 AppendTo[data, {t1[[1]], t2[[1]]}]]
data
```

gives (for 4 kernels)

```
    {{0.554032, 2.482142}, {1.297074, 9.613550}, {2.040117, 
  21.586235}, {2.843163, 37.915397}}
```

Comment: That's true. But the point is that if we have two ways for a computation on a multicore computer, to use parallelization or to use the built-in function, which one should we choose? Will the built-in functions always be  better?

Comment: i think your question would be more of a general question on when to use parallel computing. When performing the same operation (e.g., sum vs parallel sum), the parallel version should always win in performance unless the operation involved in each parallel step is too small - this is due to the fact that each parallel call has a small overhead (which is also affected by how your OS distributes the cores and processing power).

Comment: @EdenHarder:Parallelized version of the built-in function will be better.But if you break it in steps than it will not be.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I confused you all. I have updated the question. Thanks all.