# Simple while loop alternative in Mathematica

Tags: functional-style, coding-style

I have noticed that there are a few examples that go into some detail regarding While loop alternatives. (See here for example: [Alternatives to While Loops?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/alternatives-to-while-loops?rq=1)) However, I wanted to provide a simpler example for clarity, and to help affirm something which I am currently unclear about.

Can someone give a simple, faster alternative to the following code containing a While loop? (It counts the number of iterations taken before a pseudorandom uniform number on [0,1] to be generated.)

```
 Module[{cSwitch, cCount, cRand}, cSwitch = 0; cCount = 0; cRand = 0.9999;
While[cSwitch == 0, aRand = RandomReal[]; cCount += 1; 
If[aRand > cRand, cSwitch = 1]]; cCount] // Timing
```

A corollary question is, when should one use a While loop for simplicity, and when is it *really* beneficial to use an alternative? I am highlighting *really* just to emphasise that there is a tradeoff between readability of code and speed.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Just for fun: `Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, If[RandomReal[] > 0.9999, #, #0[# + 1]] &[0]]`.  Another: `NestWhile[# + 1 &, 0, RandomReal[] < 0.9999 &]`.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for a pattern suitable for loops which must terminate on a condition (rather than run a fixed number of times).  `While` is a good solution for this, but the key is really `Break[]`, which can be used in `While`, `Do`, `For`, etc.  I would write this code as

```
count = 1;
While[RandomReal[] <= 0.9999, count++];
count
```

as here you can move the condition to the beginning of `While`.  If you can't, then something like

```
While[True,
  ...
  If[condition, Break[]];
  ...
]
```

is an alternative.

(You can also use `For`, as in `For[count = 1, RandomReal[] <= 0.9999, count++]; count`, but I'm not a fan of for loops in Mathematica.  I usually prefer `While`.)

Many problems that need to break on condition can be solved with [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html).  Your example would be

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, RandomReal[] <= 0.9999 &]
```

Check the documentation to see all the possible syntaxes for `NestWhile`.

It's also possible to use recursive iteration, though it's more likely to be slower here, and we need to release the restriction on the iteration limit using `$IterationLimit = Infinity`:

```
f[n_] := If[RandomReal[] > 0.9999, n, f[n + 1]]
f[1]
```

A very concise, but arguably not too readable version of the same is `If[RandomReal[] > 0.9999, #, #0[# + 1]] & [1]`.  Here `#0` refers to the anonymous function itself.

If performance is key, then the `While` version has the advantage that it can [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html)d.  [Not every function is compilable.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions)  A procedural style, such as the version using `While`, is the most suitable to be compiled.

Comment: a very instructional answer. +1

Comment: Your nasty unreadable last piece of code can be greatly improved as the `If` isn't really needed: `Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, (# + 1 // (#0^Boole[RandomReal[] < 0.9999])) &@1 // #[[1]] &]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - that is useful to see. I have done some timing on the various different approaches to the While loop, and all seem to be very similar in terms of their timing. Can I ask if anyone could provide examples of when there is a significant difference in timing between a While loop vs a functional construct? Best, Ben